# SQL Server : select values from table if values in referenced table is equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables: units

```
  name | departament | count  |  unit_manager   

unit_1 |   dep_1     |  100   |    nick         
unit_2 |   dep_1     |  200   |    john
```

and `employees`:

```
full_name  |  unit  |  position  |  salary  |  phone_number  

    mary   | unit_2 |   clerk    |    100   |   123-45      
    nick   | unit_2 |  manager   |    200   |   24-56
```

`Employees` table has a foreign key `unit` that refers to the `name` column in `units` table.

I need to write a SQL query to select all units, in which all employees, except unit manager have the same position.

How can I do this?

All that I can find out - is the way how I can select units that have similar values from employees table

```
SELECT u.*
FROM employee s1, employee s2
INNER JOIN units u ON s2.unit = u.name
WHERE s1.full_name <> s2.full_name 
AND s1.position = s2.position
```

Comment: What was wrong with your initial effort?  Did you get an error?   Can you post it?

Comment: What are you trying to compare by employees.full_name or employees.position? you seem to have contradicting information in your data set. Is nick only a manager of unit_1 or is he also a valid manager of unit_2.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And *mixing* the two styles is **strongly** discouraged!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM employee s1
INNER JOIN employee s2 ON s1.urID = s2.urID
INNER JOIN units u ON s2.unit = u.name
WHERE s1.full_name <> s2.full_name 
AND s1.position = s2.position
```

If you are not returning the data you want try:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM employee s1
INNER JOIN employee s2 ON s1.urID = s2.urID
LEFT OUTER JOIN units u ON s2.unit = u.name
WHERE s1.full_name <> s2.full_name 
AND s1.position = s2.position
```

To get a better handle on how to do join correctly see [Jeff Atwoods article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) on Join types

Comment: @brewerof Also I know you are just trying to get a query but avoid using select *, always define your select columns even if you actually need all the columns in the table (although this is rarely the case).

Answer (score 0):

I had to take a bit of a guess as to what you wanted, but try this...
Your test data was insufficient to test the results, so I added some rows...
This will return unit_1, because all the employees in unit_1 are clerks, but not unit_2, because 1 of the employees in unit_2 is 'not a clerk' (excluding the manager)

```
create table #unit (name varchar(20),  departament varchar(20),  counta varchar(20),  unit_manager varchar(20))
insert into #unit values('unit_1','dep_1','100','nick');
insert into #unit values('unit_2','dep_1','200','john');

create table #employees(full_name varchar(20),  unit varchar(20),  position varchar(20))
insert into #employees values('nick','unit_1','manager');
insert into #employees values('mary1.1','unit_1','clerk');
insert into #employees values('mary1.2','unit_1','clerk');
insert into #employees values('mary1.3','unit_1','clerk');
insert into #employees values('mary1.4','unit_1','clerk');

insert into #employees values('john','unit_2','manager');
insert into #employees values('mary2.1','unit_2','clerk');
insert into #employees values('mary2.2','unit_2','not a clerk');
insert into #employees values('mary2.3','unit_2','clerk');
insert into #employees values('mary2.4','unit_2','clerk');


SELECT u.name AS Unit, COUNT(*) as Employees, COUNT(DISTINCT e1.Position) as Positions
FROM #unit u
    JOIN #employees e1 on u.name = e1.unit AND u.unit_manager <> e1.full_name
GROUP by u.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e1.Position) = 1
```

if you want to see a list of all the units, and how many distinct positions they have, do this

```
SELECT u.name AS Unit, COUNT(*) as Employees, COUNT(DISTINCT e1.Position) as Positions
FROM #unit u
    JOIN #employees e1 on u.name = e1.unit AND u.unit_manager <> e1.full_name
GROUP by u.name
```